# LocalDatabase- Setup installation problem

Tags: c#, connection-string, setup-project, local-database

I have c# winfrm project with Local database. I created setup File with attaching database. 
But I get following error.
A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'InventoryDb.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

It's working fine in the same computer as I have my project, but not in othet Windows 7 whe nI install it.
This is my connection string in App.config page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Db"  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\InventoryDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  /> 
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I wonder what is I'am missing? Do I have wrong connectionstring? I would appricate for your help.

Comment: Please make sure that `|DataDirectory|` is true and have permissions

Comment: @Mofid.Moghimi thank you for your response, but How can I do DataDirectory to true? and how to ckeck Permission? Thank you again

Comment: @Mofid.Moghimi  thank you for your response, but How can I do DataDirectory to true? and how to ckeck Permission? Thank you again

Comment: After install your App in target machine, your app try to go to the `|DataDirectory|` to attach your database to engine. Make sure your path in target machine is true. And your .mdf file must be have full control permission. for check permission you need to right click on .mdf & .ldf files in target machine and click `Properties`, in Security tab you can check the permission

Comment: @Mofid.Moghimi that's what I did with my files .mdf and lg files after installation was finsih. But what do you mean by "Make sure your path in target machine is true" and How to do that?

Comment: When you install your app, your app files like .dll, .exe and etc files copied in target machine.(on installation path) Your Database files also copied. So you can find .mdf & .ldf file on this path